# Fatal unable to access repository - TCP connection reset by peer

Tags: github

I'm getting `Fatal : unable to clone repository TCP connection reset by peer`. It works on other servers except a few servers.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Comment: Firewall ports, bad credentials or whitelisted ips maybe? Where are you pulling your images from?

Comment: we use github as our repositories

Comment: And your servers? Are they authenticated properly when pulling those images?

Comment: My recommendation is see what is different from those its working on as to those its not, it sounds like the issue is on the servers itself not able to fully authenticate before pulling down those images or completely unable to reach github.